# Make awk print a specific segment of a single line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file called LogsDocker that contains

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/root/.docker/machine/machines/Main-hola"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="Main-hola"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env Main-hola)
```

and i want to print only the ip

```
192.168.99.100
```

Just discovered Awk and with the command

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS = "//"} ; { print $2}' LogsDocker
```

made it print (with a bunch of empty lines)

```
192.168.99.100:2376"
```

What would be the correct way to print ONLY the ip without empty lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/DOCKER_HOST/ && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/DOCKER_HOST/ && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){      ##Checking condition if string DOCKER_HOST is found in line AND match is having a mentioned regex matched in it.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                                 ##If above conditions are TRUE then printing substring whose starting index is RSTART and ending index is RLENGTH.
}
' Input_file                                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Considering that your Input_file will always be same then try following.

```
awk -F'[/:]' '/DOCKER_HOST/{print $4}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -F'[/:]' '      ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as /or colon here.
/DOCKER_HOST/{      ##Checking condition if a line has string DOCKER_HOST then do following.
  print $4          ##Printing 4th field of current line.
}
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** A `sed` solution.

```
sed -n '/DOCKER_HOST/s/.*\///;s/:.*//p'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Following is only for explanation purposes.

```
sed -n '          ##Starting sed program from here and making printing off for all lines until specifically mentioned.
/DOCKER_HOST/     ##Searching string DOCKER_HOST in lines if present then do following.
s/                ##s means perform substitution operation here.
.*\/              ##mentioning regex which covers everything till / in line, if matched this regex
//                ##Then substitute it with NULL here.
;                 ##semi colon denotes to segregate another substitute operation after this one.
s/                ##Doing substitution from here.
:.*               ##Match everything from : to till last of line.
//                ##Substitute above matched values with NULL in current line.
p                 ##p means only print this line.
'  Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, what is sed and how it differs with awk?

Comment: @thrash3d, I added complete explanations for my solutions it may help you. Also `sed` is a stream editor, more information you can get it by googling it or by its man page too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming given your existing code that the IP address is the only place you have `//`:

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*\/\//,""){sub(/:.*/,""); print}' file
192.168.99.100
```

or making other assumptions...:

```
$ awk -F'//|:' 'NF>2{print $3}' file
192.168.99.100
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'//|:' '/DOCKER_HOST=/{print $3}' file
192.168.99.100
```

or ....

It really just depends what else is in that file and how robust you want it to be.

Comment: Both work, could you explain the logic behind them? thanks

Comment: I think they're pretty self-explanatory - is there anything in particular you don't understand about any of them?

Comment: this particular part in the first (/.*\/\//,""){sub(/:.*/,"") as i understand, it sets the start of the line to be // and the end to be : ? 
And also 
-F'//|:' in the second, you use | to separate the start and end of the print?

Comment: No. You should google an awk tutorial as you misunderstand basic syntax. Awk is a series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements where the action is executed when the condition is true, all wrapped in an implicit `while read line` loop and with each line split into fields based on the value of FS as set by `-F` in this case. The first command is removing everything up to `//` and if that succeeded then removing everything from `:` on and printing whats left. The 2nd is printing the text betwee `//` and `:` when such exists.